# MsgBox SelectionChange define range

Tags: vba, optimization, msgbox

I have written the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myValue As Variant
If Range("B22") = "Yes" Then
        myValue = InputBox("InsertInitialDetach")
        Range("C22").Value = myValue
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is meant to do the following thing: If I select Yes from a Yes/No drop down list, a message box appears and asks me to fill in a date. 
The problem is that even after I fill the date, whatever I do afterwards, the box keeps on appearing and asking for the date. If I move two cells down, for example, the popup will continue to ask me for a date. 
Please tell me what should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Selection Change is triggered when you change the selected range or cell, Are you sure you don't want to use Change instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the selectionChange event which triggers after any change in the area selected, if want to trigger on value changes use the change event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myValue As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrorOccured
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        myValue = InputBox("Insert initialDetach")
        Range("B2").Value = myValue
    End If
    ErrorOccured:
    'Do when value is not valid
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Zoilo Reyes. I have now understood my mistake.

Comment: If you select `B1:B2` and press delete, the code explodes in error `13`.

Answer (score 2):

Would this be ok:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myValue As Variant
    If (Not Intersect(Range("B22"), Target) Is Nothing) And (Range("B22") = "Yes") Then
        myValue = InputBox("InsertInitialDetach")
        Range("C22").Value = myValue
    End If
End Sub
```

It checks every time whether you are changing `Range("B22")` and whether `Range("B22")` "Yes".

Comment: Vityata, thank you for your help. I ran the code and I get this error message: "Object variable or With block variable not set".

Comment: @RobertC - this is what happens when I write code and I do not test it. See the update.

Comment: Indeed it works, Vityata. Thank you for your help and for making me understand the lack of the synthax in the initial code.